# Can I create custom error pages that also work with website monitoring sites?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I've managed to set up custom .net error pages in IIS and they are working fine. However my website status monitoring does not work, because my custom error page is not technically an error, as it came from a redirect.

How does everyone else do this?

Thanks